# To involve SharePoint WCF Service with SSL-Certificate from Client laptop failed

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, ssl-certificate

My testing environment is:

- 1* Server :: SharePoint Site with WCF Service (in the ISAPI folder) and we configured the SSL and Cert on it.
- 1* Client :: Windows 10 with one Console Application to involve the WCF service

Testing (1) :all programs (WCF Service and Console Application) on the SharePoint Server

I created a Console application to invoke the WCF Service in SharePoint. Meantime, the Console application and WCF are on the same server. the outcome is everything works properly. It is successful to upload file into a Document Library.

Testing (2) :to simulate my client environment:

- 1* SharePoint :WCF Service
- 1* Windows 10 :Console application

the outcome failed and I got the error message:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'

To be honest, I stuck here for a while. I also list out a portion of my source code for someone of experience to look at. I also posted some sample code and web.config in [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3192168c-7307-4d05-b766-55a6bbb5eeef/reraise-the-sharepoint-wcf-question-once-again?forum=sharepointdevelopment).

Comment: Please post the source code web.config *here* within the question, not on some third party site.

Comment: Your console app must *authenticate* to SharePoint. The error message you are getting says that it's not passing any credentials ('Anonymous'), while the server is configured to expect NTLM authentication.

Comment: Hi Ondrej, I would like to post the web.config here. but the XML string is too long over the limitation... so I still upload to my office365. If you are willing to download it, please from here [link]https://spexphk-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/will_spexphk_onmicrosoft_com/EQ4FKGjaSllDnkwcnEDF_ogBfDnbntEnLCjcN8QtihQafw?e=aSdYON

Answer (score 0):

**Updated.**
If we enable NTLM authentication, we have to enable the windows authentication.
[image]
Then when calling the service, we need to provide windows credential.

```
//it will use the binding and service endpoint address in the system.servicemode section.
        ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
                //windows account on the server.
                client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
                client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "abcd1234!";
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(client.SayHello());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
```

Auto-generated configuration.

```
   <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://vabqia969vm:21011/" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="VABQIA969VM\Administrator" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Hi Abraham, (1) Windows authentication --> default is enabled (2) https://extlab.litwareinc.pri/... --> could connect (3) Why do I use the following code to connect to the Service --> When I use the BasicHttpBinding, I use the same code to do it and work properly. so we just change the BaiscHttpBinding to WSHttpBinding, the most of source code will be the same. Of course, the security.mode or transport will be difference. you could download it from [link]https://spexphk-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/will_spexphk_onmicrosoft_com/EQ4FKGjaSllDnkwcnEDF_ogBfDnbntEnLCjcN8QtihQafw?e=aSdYON

Comment: Hi Abraham, "the service address should be generated automatically in the client configuration file." --> you mean I need to create a config file for the SharePoint WebPart, console, or other types of program?? but when I use the BasicHttpBinding and use Window Authentication, I don't do it and work properly

Comment: No, if we call the service by a client proxy, which we usually generate by adding service reference. meanwhile, the System.servicemodel section in the configuration file will be generated automatically too. Thereby I want to check the configuration.
Besides, Have you provided the username/password when call the service?

Comment: ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "administrator";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "abcd1234!";

Comment: Abraham, I share the url of web.config ([link]https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aj2Mcyp8XWC1g8t8hC8agR6rhgU-Aw). Please refer to the link. thanks. [meanwhile, the System.servicemodel section in the configuration file will be generated automatically too] --> this mean even though I add WCF service from VS .NET, I also need to  use generated all settings once again??? Another thing is I have provided the username/ password into my source code yesterday and have it a try. the same error message comes up. I doubt whether or not my cert isn't configured correctly ...

Comment: Yes, it will directly use the settings in the configuration file when you instantiate the client proxy class. Therefore, the only thing we need to do is changing the default service endpoint address (sometimes it will generate the Localhost instead of the practical server address).

Comment: Besides, since we use NTLM authentication, which belongs to the Windows authentication, we should provide the credential by the below form.
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "abcd1234!";